# how do i assign top 2, middle 2 and bottom 2 values with extra in the given data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

In the given below data frame. i want to insert a new column with extra and assign, top 2, middle two and below two values as "Extra"
df

```
A_No    B_Wt
    39  184.66
    40  193.11
    46  197.82
    2   203.82
    12  205.27
    9   208.11
    3   208.49
    14  208.70
```

Out put

```
A_No B_Wt   Group
39  184.66  Extra
40  193.11  Extra
46  197.82
2   203.82  Extra
12  205.27  Extra
9   208.11
3   208.49  Extra
14  208.70  Extra
```

Comment: Is there some rule why you want to assign `Extra` on those places? Will the dataframe have always the same number of rows?

Comment: There is no rule that the number of rows on data frame is same. I sorted the values B_Wt from low to high and i wanted to assign low mid and high weighted animals as extra. The number of extra animals is also not fixed, some times 10, some times 15 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use join positions for top2, middle2 and bottom2 together and then set values to new column:

```
lend = len(df)
mid = lend // 2

pos = np.r_[0:2, mid-1:mid+1, lend-2:lend]
df.loc[df.index[pos], 'Group'] = 'Extra'
print (df)
   A_No    B_Wt  Group
0    39  184.66  Extra
1    40  193.11  Extra
2    46  197.82    NaN
3     2  203.82  Extra
4    12  205.27  Extra
5     9  208.11    NaN
6     3  208.49  Extra
7    14  208.70  Extra
```